# Ionic proxy not working with ionic CLI

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have added proxy in ionic.project

```
{
  "name": "UNDP-App",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies":[
    {
    "path":"/api",
    "proxyUrl":"http://192.168.0.109/urautodeals/public/api"
  }
  ]
}
```

As I run the ionic command **ionic serve --lab**, it did not load the proxy as shown in image below.

[image: Image of CLI]

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Ionic version is 1.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Ionic CLI to 3.19.0 fixed this for me. At the command line, enter:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Note this does not change which framework version (1.3.1) you are using.